# Is it possible to post back a form to rendering on another item/page?

Tags: mvc-forms

Is it possible to post data from a form with controller rendering on page1 to a controller rendering on page2?

I mean the form submit on page1 should post back with page2 as page context.

Update 1:
tried below option of adding scItemPath in route.. no luck

https://jockstothecore.com/to-the-controller-and-back-part-1-routing/

scItemPath passed in routevalues is appending to route like controller/action/{scItemPath}, but not invoking the pagecontext of item id passed.

Update 2: adding code

view (rendered using conroller rendering on item1)

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { scItemPath = "path/to/item2"}, FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "selectLoginCredentialsForm", @class = "adjacent_error_wrap", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("RegistrationSecurity", "SetSecurityDetails")
//form inputs
<input name="username" type=text/>
<input name="password" type=text/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

Controller

```
 public class RegistrationSecurityController : GlassController
{

    public ActionResult SetSecurityDetails(UserCredentials creds)
    {
        var model = GetDataSourceItem<Idatasource>();
        return View("~/Views/path/to/view.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can call $.ajax method on button click. on success set window.location.href. you can keep form data into session.

Comment: @AbhishekMalaviya - thought of this solution, but do not want to use session for storing and retrieving sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You may invoke child ajax method on success and pass login form data to this ajax method.
Here child ajax method will call another page controller action method.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
        var formdata = $("#frmLogin").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#frmLogin").attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == "Success") {
                    // Now call another ajax method to pass data
                     $.ajax({
                     url: //pass another page controller action,
                     type: "POST",
                     data: formdata,
                     success: function (result) { }                
                     });
            },
            error: function (Error) {

            }

        });
    });
```

Hopefully this will help you.